# setting value in combo box

Tags: javascript, html

I have a  check box  like this:

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-4" style="text-align: left">Select</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <select id="is_selected" data-key="is_selected"
        class="form-control ">
            <option value="999" disabled selected>Select </option>
        <option  value="1">True</option>
        <option value="0">False</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And from server side true or false is getting. I want to dynamically select "true" in combo box if the value from server side is true. and "false" if its false.

Comment: Which language you're using?

Comment: where is the server side code show us

Answer (score 2):

For javascript:

```
document.getElementById("is_selected").selectedIndex = 1;
```

Find the fiddle here: [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dilani_di/8bqr8yek/)